# How to avoid moving in the opossite direction

Tags: python, pygame

I'm implementing and "IA" to my ghost in my copy of Pac-Man, the ghost when hit a block check for every way it can go, but one of that ways is the opposite direction he was taking and that makes that for example if hits a block while moving left, then move right, and then hit a block and move left again, how can I avoid that? I tried doing a "oppositeDirection" variable that changes depending where it the block but the ghost keep doig the same

```
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *


pygame.init()


#Variables del juego
windowWidth = 504
windowHeight = 648
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowHeight), 0, 32)
mainClock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 30


pygame.display.set_caption('Pac-Man')


#Colores
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
yellow = (255, 255, 0)
cyan = (0, 255, 255)
navyBlue = (0, 0, 53)
pink = (255, 192, 203)


#Tamaño del bloque

blockSize = 24
dotSize = 4
pillSize = 10

#Datos del jugador
playerSize = 24
player = pygame.Rect(240, 480, playerSize, playerSize)
speed = 5


#Datos del fantasma
ghostSize = 24
player = pygame.Rect(240, 480, playerSize, playerSize)
ghostSpeed = 4



#Variables de movimiento del jugador
moveLeft = moveRight = moveDown = moveUp = False


#Variables del fantasma
ghost = pygame.Rect(240, 480, ghostSize, ghostSize)
ghostMoveLeft = 1
ghostMoveRight  = 2
ghostMoveUp  = 3
ghostMoveDown = 4
ghostCurrentDirection = None
ghostPossibleMove = []
ghostOpossiteDirection = None

#Laberinto
maze = [
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "x.........x.........x",
    "x.xxx.xxx.x.xxx.xxx.x",
    "x-xxx.xxx.x.xxx.xxx-x",
    "x.xxx.xxx.x.xxx.xxx.x",
    "x...................x",
    "x.xxx.x.xxxxx.x.xxx.x",
    "x.xxx.x.xxxxx.x.xxx.x",
    "x.....x...x...x.....x",
    "xxxxx.xxxoxoxxx.xxxxx",
    "oooox.xooooooox.xoooo",
    "oooox.xoxxoxxox.xoooo",
    "xxxxx.xoxoooxox.xxxxx",
    "ooooo.ooxoooxoo.ooooo",
    "xxxxx.xoxxxxxox.xxxxx",
    "oooox.xooooooox.xoooo",
    "oooox.xoxxxxxox.xoooo",
    "xxxxx.xoxxxxxox.xxxxx",
    "x.........x.........x",
    "x.xxx.xxx.x.xxx.xxx.x",
    "x-..x.....o.....x..-x",
    "xxx.x.x.xxxxx.x.x.xxx",
    "xxx.x.x.xxxxx.x.x.xxx",
    "x.....x...x...x.....x",
    "x.xxxxxxx.x.xxxxxxx.x",
    "x...................x",
    "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

]
def createMaze():
    pointX = 0
    pointY = 0
    y = 0
    for i in maze:
        x = 0
        for j in i:
            if j == "x":
                block = pygame.Rect(pointX, pointY, blockSize, blockSize)
                pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, navyBlue, block)

                global ghostCurrentDirection
                if block.colliderect(player):
                    if player.bottom - block.top <  10:
                        player.y = block.top - playerSize
                    if block.bottom - player.top < 10:             
                        player.y = block.bottom
                    if block.right - player.left < 10:
                        player.x = block.right
                    if  player.right - block.left < 10:
                        player.x = block.left - playerSize


                global ghostPossibleMove
                global ghostOpossiteDirection
                if ghost.right is not block.left:
                    ghostPossibleMove.append(ghostMoveRight)
                if ghost.left is not block.right:
                    ghostPossibleMove.append(ghostMoveLeft)
                if ghost.top is not block.bottom:
                    ghostPossibleMove.append(ghostMoveDown)
                if ghost.bottom is not block.top:
                    ghostPossibleMove.append(ghostMoveUp)
                
                if ghostCurrentDirection == None:
                    ghostCurrentDirection = random.choice(ghostPossibleMove)
                    ghostPossibleMove = []
                if ghostCurrentDirection == ghostOpossiteDirection:
                    ghostCurrentDirection = None
                else:
                    pass
                


                if block.colliderect(ghost):
                    if ghost.bottom - block.top <  10:
                        ghost.y = block.top - playerSize
                        ghostCurrentDirection = None
                        ghostOpossiteDirection = ghostMoveUp
                    if block.bottom - ghost.top < 10:             
                        ghost.y = block.bottom
                        ghostCurrentDirection = None
                        ghostOpossiteDirection = ghostMoveDown
                    if block.right - ghost.left < 10:
                        ghost.x = block.right
                        ghostCurrentDirection = None
                        ghostOpossiteDirection = ghostMoveRight
                    if  ghost.right - block.left < 10:
                        ghost.x = block.left - playerSize
                        ghostCurrentDirection = None
                        ghostOpossiteDirection = ghostMoveLeft
            if j == ".":
                dot = pygame.Rect(pointX + (blockSize / 2) - (dotSize / 2), pointY + (blockSize / 2) - (dotSize / 2), dotSize, dotSize)
                pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, white, dot)
                if dot.colliderect(player):
                    maze[y] = maze[y][:x] + "o" + maze[y][x + 1:]
            if j == "-":
                pill =  pygame.Rect(pointX + (blockSize / 2) - (pillSize / 2), pointY + (blockSize / 2) - (pillSize / 2), pillSize, pillSize)
                pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, white, pill)
                if pill.colliderect(player):
                    maze[y] = maze[y][:x] + "o" + maze[y][x + 1:]
            if j == "o":
                pass
            pointX += blockSize
            x += 1

        pointX = 0
        pointY += blockSize
        y += 1

#Función para cerrar juego
def close():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()


#Ciclo principal del juego
while True:
    #Buscar evento QUIT
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            close()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_w:
                moveUp = True
                moveDown = False
                moveLeft = False
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_s:                
                moveUp = False
                moveDown = True
                moveLeft = False
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_a:
                moveUp = False
                moveDown = False
                moveLeft = True
                moveRight = False
            if event.key == K_d:
                moveUp = False
                moveDown = False
                moveLeft = False
                moveRight = True


            if event.key == K_c:
                ghostCurrentDirection =  random.choice(ghostPossibleMove)


    #Mover jugador
    if moveLeft:
        player.move_ip(-1 * speed, 0)
    if moveRight:
        player.move_ip(speed, 0)
    if moveUp:
        player.move_ip(0, -1 * speed)
    if moveDown:
        player.move_ip(0, speed)



    #Mover al fantasma
    # if ghost.x % 24 == 0:
    #     ghostCurrentDirection =  random.choice(ghostPossibleMove)


    if ghostCurrentDirection == ghostMoveLeft:
        ghost.move_ip(-1 * ghostSpeed, 0)
    if ghostCurrentDirection == ghostMoveRight:
        ghost.move_ip(ghostSpeed, 0)
    if ghostCurrentDirection == ghostMoveUp:
        ghost.move_ip(0, -1 * ghostSpeed)
    if ghostCurrentDirection == ghostMoveDown:
        ghost.move_ip(0, ghostSpeed)


    #Portal
    if player.left > windowWidth:
        player.x = 0 - playerSize
    if player.right < 0:
        player.x = windowWidth

    windowSurface.fill(black)
    
    createMaze()
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, yellow, player)
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface, cyan, ghost)
    

    pygame.display.update()

    mainClock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the direction he was heading.  Make the opposite of that direction be the *last* possible choice.  If you want to do a little more work, keep track of each block visited (a simple Boolean map), and when there is a choice to make, then sort the directions of any visited blocks to the end of the choice list.